# How to search nearby places, given a pair of latitude, longitude using google maps apis

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have a simple requirement: **Display nearby places, sorted in ascending order of distance from the current user.**

The `places` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE places (
 id int(11) NOT NULL ,
 category varchar(200) ,
 name varchar(200) ,
 address varchar(2000) ,
 city varchar(100) ,
 state varchar(100) ,
 zipcode varchar(20) ,
 country varchar(100) ,
 latitude decimal(12,9) ,
 longitude decimal(12,9) ,
 phone varchar(200) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I request user to allow browser to access his location (or find appox. location using ip). Having his latitude, longitude, address, city and country, I have 2 options to find nearby places:

1) Calculate a min, max range of lat, lng in lets say 5-10 miles radius from user's coordinates. Then do a:

```
SELECT * FROM places  
    WHERE (latitude  between MINLAT  and MAXLAT )  
    and   (longitude between MINLNG and MAXLNG) 
    and category = CATEGORY
```

This probably means my server will be doomed with all the calculations. Another problem is I cannot sort the results based on actual distance from the user.

2) Another option is to Select all places in the same city as user's. Then, on client side, calculate distance between user and each place using geo api's javascript functions, and display in ascending order. Downside is that server needs to send all `places` in a city to client (which maybe anything between .1k - 10k)

Which the best alternative considering all tradeoffs? Is there any other option?

Planning to use LAMP but I can change technology stack if any other combination is faster. (suggest on this too)

Comment: hi dear Jerrymouse - many thanks for this interesting thread with this approach. This looks pretty impressive. Did you come along with this solution? look forward to hear from you - greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say do as much as you can on the server side.  I'm not sure why you think that query "means my server will be doomed with all the calculations".  Also I think you could do the sorting too; you'd just need to add a temp column to your query based on the actual distance from the user.  I don't know the formula, but I assume it's do-able in SQL.

Comment: If all the calculations are done on the server side for each user request, the server load will increase exponentially. I want to delegate the distance calculation and sorting part to client side, to save server resources